# Is there a selector to disable Bootstrap inside a block?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a selector to disable Bootstrap inside a block? I need the Bootstrap CSS styles not to work inside the div.

Comment: use an iframe  ..

Answer (score 1):

Just override the Bootstrap style. As long as Bootstrap is included on your page before your custom CSS then your CSS should override Bootstrap as the specificity of the selector would be the same. Add this to your custom CSS and override the styles accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe in div in which you don't want to load bootstrap